# Assume pagination=none as default unless defined otherwise

Tags: biblatex

In the text I'm writing I don't want a page prefix like 'p.' where simple pages are concerned, but still want to keep the prefix elsewhere (e.g. for columns, verse, sections etc.). Thus, setting `\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}` is not an option. I tried to help myself temporarily by defining

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  page = {},
  pages = {},
}
```

However, this comes with the catch that the `\notecite` commands don't work properly and introduce a superfluous space before the page number:

[image: Formatting of \textcite, \notecite, \autocite, and \pnotecite]

Since I've already tracked the problem down to this, my question is, how I can define the `postnote` field format to default to `none` instead of `page` unless it is defined otherwise by an entry's `pagination` option, e.g. as `verse` etc. That is, what I want are citations of the kind *Doe (1986: 123)* and *(45)*, but defined in a way to keep *Ample (1971: v. 2345)* and *(v. 678)*.

---

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
  style=unified,
  backend=biber,
  natbib,
]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  page = {},
  pages = {},
}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{doe1986,
  author = {John F. Doe},
  title = {A book with a title},
  publisher = {Erewhon University Press},
  location = {Erewhon},
  date = {1986},
}

@book{ample1971,
  editor = {Jane X. Ample},
  title = {James the {W}riter},
  subtitle = {The noble knight of {S}omeplaceshire},
  publisher = {Erewhon University Press},
  location = {Erewhon},
  date = {1971},
  pagination = {verse},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\noindent
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \textcite[123]{doe1986}. \\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \notecite[45]{doe1986}. \\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \autocite[123]{doe1986}. \\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \pnotecite[45]{doe1986}. \\

\noindent
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \textcite[2345]{ample1971}. \\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \notecite[678]{ample1971}. \\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \autocite[2345]{ample1971}. \\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \pnotecite[678]{ample1971}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple solution is to have a Biber sourcemap set the `pagination = {none},` for all entries without a `pagination` field in the `.bib` file.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
  style=unified,
  backend=biber,
  natbib,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldset=pagination, fieldvalue={none}]
    }
  }
}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{doe1986,
  author    = {John F. Doe},
  title     = {A Book with a Title},
  publisher = {Erewhon University Press},
  location  = {Erewhon},
  date      = {1986},
}
@book{ample1971,
  editor     = {Jane X. Ample},
  title      = {James the {Writer}},
  subtitle   = {The Noble Knight of {Someplaceshire}},
  publisher  = {Erewhon University Press},
  location   = {Erewhon},
  date       = {1971},
  pagination = {verse},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \textcite[123]{doe1986}.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \notecite[45]{doe1986}.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \autocite[123]{doe1986}.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \pnotecite[45]{doe1986}.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \textcite[2345]{ample1971}.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \notecite[678]{ample1971}.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \autocite[2345]{ample1971}.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \pnotecite[678]{ample1971}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Doe (1986: 123). Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 45. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet (Doe 1986: 123). Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet (45). Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Ample (1971: v. 2345). Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet v. 678. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet (Ample 1971: v. 2345). Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet (v. 678).]

---

Alternatively, you can redefine the internal definition of `\mkpageprefix` to behave as though the 'default' value for `pagination` is `none`.

```
\makeatletter
\renewrobustcmd*{\blx@imc@mkpageprefix}[1][pagination]{%
  \begingroup
  \def\blx@tempa{\blx@mkpageprefix@i}%
  \iffieldundef{#1}
    {}
    {\iffieldequalstr{#1}{none}
       {\def\blx@tempa{\blx@mkpageprefix@i}}
       {\iffieldbibstring{#1}
          {\edef\blx@tempa{\blx@mkpageprefix{\thefield{#1}}}}
          {\blx@warning@entry{%
             Unknown pagination type '\strfield{#1}'}}}}%
  \@ifnextchar[%]
    {\blx@tempa}
    {\blx@tempa[\@firstofone]}}
\makeatother
```

Since this relies on the internals of the command `\mkpageprefix` this solution is less stable.